# Dropping constant columns in a csv file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i would like to drop columns which are constant in a dataframe , here what i did , but i see that it tooks some much time to do it , special while writing the dataframe into the csv file , please any help to optimize the code to take less time

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "false").csv("D:\\ProcessDataSet\\anis_data\\Set _1Mud Pumps_Merged.csv")
val aggregations = df.drop("DateTime").columns.map(c => stddev("c").as(c)) 
val df2 = df.agg(aggregations.head, aggregations.tail: _*)
val columnsToKeep: Seq[String] = (df2.first match {
  case r : Row => r.toSeq.toArray.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double])
}).zip(df.columns)
  .filter(_._1 != 0) // your special condition is in the filter
  .map(_._2) // keep just the name of the column
// select columns with stddev != 0
val finalResult = df.select(columnsToKeep.head, columnsToKeep.tail : _*)
finalResult.write.option("header",true).csv("D:\\ProcessDataSet\\dataWithoutConstant\\Set _1Mud Pumps_MergedCleaned.csv")

}
```

Comment: Actually, how much time does it take to write the CSV file ?
And what is the size of your input data ?

Comment: @L.CWI the file is 1.4 gega ,it took 5 minutes to write to csv .it took to much comparing to the time taken to compute.is there any suggestion ?Thanks

Comment: @L.CWI would you please help , what is the fastest way to save dataframe into a csv file thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no much room left for optimization. You are doing the right thing.

Maybe what you can try is to `cache()` your dataframe `df`.

`df` is used in two separate Spark actions so it is loaded twice.

Try :

```
...
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "false").csv("D:\\ProcessDataSet\\anis_data\\Set _1Mud Pumps_Merged.csv")
df.cache()
val aggregations = df.drop("DateTime").columns.map(c => stddev("c").as(c))
...
```